# WebService in JqueryMobile(Response in Json)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, json, web-services

I'm doing a  project in Jquery Mobiles and need an webservice. Normally in android we have the http connection and we got the response as xml/json etc.. We parse the data and processed to the view. Here,In case of jquery , facing problem to solve the issue.. I read that ajax call is using for the webservices.

Sample code

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "some url",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
        //$("#resultLog").html(msg);
    }
});
```

Also,I refer the google api_Place Search, the service for this is entirely different

RefernceLink [Click HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search)!

Does anyone suggest the proper way to implement the webservice to interact with my server and retrieve the json response?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Your question is a little confusing.  Are you asking how to write a webservice or how to use the Google maps API?

Comment: @Archer . Need a guidance to write a webservice in Jquery Mobile

Comment: You don't write a web service in jQuery Mobile.  A web service sits on your web server and is written in a server-side language such as PHP or ASP.Net (amongst many others).  I think you have too little understanding of the scale of what you are asking, and it's certainly far too much to ask someone on here to do.  What server language are you using?  I'll happily point you in the direction of some good starting points.

Comment: I'm using php as the server side language . My doubt is in webservice request and response in JQuery . Really thanks for your valuable response @Archer

Comment: This previously asked question looks like a good starting point.  It's basic but suits your needs... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php